# The mean of a normally distributed variable to the fourth power

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Suppose that I have a random variable $X\sim\mathcal{N}\left(0,1\right)$.

I know that
$$\mathbb{E}\left[X\right]=0$$
$$\mathbb{E}\left[X^{2}\right]=\operatorname{var}\left(X\right)+\left(\mathbb{E}\left[X\right]\right)^{2}=1-0=1$$
But then how would I calculate $\mathbb{E}\left[X^{4}\right]$?

(By the way, I do not have any background in moments and moment generating functions, so could I request for more explanation if your response involves moments and moment generating functions please?)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$EX^{4}=\frac 1 {\sqrt {2\pi}} \int_{\mathbb R} x^{4}e^{-x^{2}/2} dx$. To evaluate $\int_{\mathbb R} x^{4}e^{-x^{2}/2} dx$ write $x^{4}$ as $(x^{3}) (x)$ and club the second factor with $e^{-x^{2}/2} $. Note that $xe^{-x^{2}/2}$ is the derivative of $-e^{-x^{2}/2} $. Integration by parts gives $EX^{4}=-x^{3}e^{-x^{2}/2}|_{-\infty}^{\infty} +3 \int_{\mathbb R} x^{2}e^{-x^{2}/2} dx$. The last integral is nothing but $\sqrt {2\pi}$ since $EX^{2}=1$. Hence $EX^{4}=3$.